# Get the proportion of rows smaller than a variable

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a R dataframe like this:

```
misc data
a    0.0
a    0.1
a    0.2
b    0.0
b    0.2
b    0.3
c    0.0
c    0.4
c    0.6
```

My goal is to create another dataframe, that will contain, for each possible value of `data` in a given range (for example `seq(0.0, 10.0, by = 0.01)`) and each value of `misc`, the proportion, among the rows with the same `misc` value, of the rows with a value of `data` inferior to the given value.

For example, with the given dataframe, I would have:

```
misc data   proportion
a    0.0    0.0
a    0.05   0.333
a    0.1    0.333
a    0.15   0.666
a    0.2    0.666
a    0.25   1.0
a    0.3    1.0
...
c    0.0    0.0
c    0.05   0.333
c    0.1    0.333
c    0.15   0.333
c    0.2    0.333
c    0.25   0.333
c    0.3    0.333
c    0.35   0.333
c    0.4    0.333
c    0.45   0.666
c    0.5    0.666
c    0.55   0.666
c    0.6    0.666
c    0.65   1.0
c    0.7    1.0
```

How can I accomplish this ? I'm still very new to R so a simple solution would be preferred
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, we need the framework with all unique `misc` and the sequence of `data` values:

```r
eg <- expand.grid(misc = unique(quux$misc), data = seq(0, 0.7, by = 0.1))
head(eg)
#   misc data
# 1    a  0.0
# 2    b  0.0
# 3    c  0.0
# 4    a  0.1
# 5    b  0.1
# 6    c  0.1
```

## dplyr

Using a two-step join and summarize:

```r
eg %>%
  left_join(quux, by = "misc", suffix = c("", ".y"), relationship = "many-to-many") %>%
  summarize(proportion = sum(data.y <= data) / n(), .by = c("misc", "data"))
#    misc data proportion
# 1     a  0.0  0.3333333
# 2     b  0.0  0.3333333
# 3     c  0.0  0.3333333
# 4     a  0.1  0.6666667
# 5     b  0.1  0.3333333
# 6     c  0.1  0.3333333
# 7     a  0.2  1.0000000
# 8     b  0.2  0.6666667
# 9     c  0.2  0.3333333
# 10    a  0.3  1.0000000
# 11    b  0.3  1.0000000
# 12    c  0.3  0.3333333
# 13    a  0.4  1.0000000
# 14    b  0.4  1.0000000
# 15    c  0.4  0.6666667
# 16    a  0.5  1.0000000
# 17    b  0.5  1.0000000
# 18    c  0.5  0.6666667
# 19    a  0.6  1.0000000
# 20    b  0.6  1.0000000
# 21    c  0.6  1.0000000
# 22    a  0.7  1.0000000
# 23    b  0.7  1.0000000
# 24    c  0.7  1.0000000
```

## base R

Row-wise summing of the conditions:

```r
eg$proportion <- mapply(
  function(m, d) with(quux, sum(misc == m & data <= d) / sum(misc == m)), 
  eg$misc, eg$data)
eg
#    misc data proportion
# 1     a  0.0  0.3333333
# 2     b  0.0  0.3333333
# 3     c  0.0  0.3333333
# 4     a  0.1  0.6666667
# 5     b  0.1  0.3333333
# 6     c  0.1  0.3333333
# 7     a  0.2  1.0000000
# 8     b  0.2  0.6666667
# 9     c  0.2  0.3333333
# 10    a  0.3  1.0000000
# 11    b  0.3  1.0000000
# 12    c  0.3  0.3333333
# 13    a  0.4  1.0000000
# 14    b  0.4  1.0000000
# 15    c  0.4  0.6666667
# 16    a  0.5  1.0000000
# 17    b  0.5  1.0000000
# 18    c  0.5  0.6666667
# 19    a  0.6  1.0000000
# 20    b  0.6  1.0000000
# 21    c  0.6  1.0000000
# 22    a  0.7  1.0000000
# 23    b  0.7  1.0000000
# 24    c  0.7  1.0000000
```